# Non-clickable QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, button

I've been trying to make a Qt test app to put two different 'scenes' in, using one main widget which is the window which can hide and show the two other widgets which are the different scenes. In scene 1, there is a QPushButton, which is connected to a signal which is connected to showing scene 2. However, when I click the button, nothing happens. I tried running in debug mode, and the first slot isn't fired, AND the animation of pushing the button down isn't triggering. Is this something to do with the fact that the button is inside a widget inside a widget? I'll add the code if necessary.

Comment: provide a **[mcve]**

Comment: @lolad add the code.